# Which NDSolve method is most effective for the given chaotic system?

Tags: plotting, conditional, code-review, head

**Note:** This question is for those chaotic systems where the order of maximal Lyapunov exponent is around $10^{-3}$. So it's different from normal chaotic systems like [Hénon–Heiles system](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204648/78049), [Yang-Mills-Higgs System](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/290227/78049), [Double Pendulum](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40122/78049) or the famous [Lorenz Attractor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/222656/78049).

**The related problem:** I am trying to reproduce my results for the Poincaré section published [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/JHEP06(2023)178) (Specifically one of the sub-figures in Figure $8$ on page $15$ given below), which I plotted by making use of an [algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267697/78049) developed by @[Alex Trounev](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/58388/alex-trounev). I am trying to plot the same this time by a different [interactive algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/296839/78049) of @[E. Chan-López](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53427/e-chan-l%C3%B3pez).

[image: poincare-string]

The code being used is as follows:

```
lagrangian = (8 x[t]^2)/3 + (4 x[t]^3)/3 - 6 y[t]^2 + 
   148/7 x[t] y[t]^2 + Derivative[1][x][t]^2 + 
   1/3 y[t] Derivative[1][x][t] Derivative[1][y][t] + 
   Derivative[1][y][t]^2 + 1/5  x[t]  Derivative[1][y][t]^2;

Px = D[lagrangian, x'[t]];
Py = D[lagrangian, y'[t]];
hamiltonian = ((Px x'[t] + Py y'[t]) - 
      lagrangian) /. (Solve[{px[t] == Px, py[t] == Py}, {x'[t], 
        y'[t]}] // Last) // FullSimplify;

{a1, b1, c1, d1} = {D[hamiltonian, px[t]], 
  D[hamiltonian, 
   py[t]], -D[hamiltonian, x[t]], -D[hamiltonian, 
    y[t]]}; hameqns = {x'[t] == a1, px'[t] == c1, y'[t] == b1, 
  py'[t] == d1};

constraint = 
 FullSimplify[
  Last[(py0 /. 
     Solve[e == (hamiltonian /. {x[t] -> x0, px[t] -> px0, y[t] -> 0, 
          py[t] -> py0}), py0])]]

PoincareSections[{x0_, px0_, y0_, py0_}, e_, tmax_] := 
 Block[{constraint, x, px, y, py}, 
  constraint = (
   I Sqrt[5 + x0] Sqrt[-12 e + 3 px0^2 - 16 x0^2 (2 + x0)])/Sqrt[15];
  If[Head[N[constraint]] === Complex, Nothing, 
   If[# == {}, {}, First[#]] &@
    Last[Reap[
      NDSolve[{hameqns, x[0] == x0, px[0] == px0, y[0] == y0, 
        py[0] == constraint, 
        WhenEvent[y[t], 
         Sow[{x[t], px[t]}, "LocationMethod" -> "EvenLocator"]]}, {x, 
        px, y, py}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> ∞, 
       MaxStepSize -> 0.1]]]]]

style = {PlotStyle -> {{AbsolutePointSize[1], Opacity[0.4]}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 420, PlotHighlighting -> None};

DynamicModule[{f = {}}, 
 Column[{Dynamic[
    MatrixForm@{MousePosition["Graphics", "Mouse not in graphics!"]}],
    Row[{ClickPane[
      Dynamic@ListPlot[f, 
        style], (AppendTo[f, 
         PoincareSections[{#[[1]], #[[2]], 0, 0}, 10^-5, 3000]]) &], 
     Button[Style["Copy orbit list", 12], 
      CopyToClipboard[Iconize[f, "Orbit list"]], 
      ImageSize -> Automatic, Alignment -> Center, 
      Appearance -> {"Palette", "Pressed"}]}, "  "]}, 
  Alignment -> Center]]
```

Now, the above algorithm doesn't work simply because the `Head` of the constraint turns out to be complex. But if we calculate it, technically, it's not a complex number. A simple example can explain the reason:

**The issue:**

```
a = N[constraint] /. x0 -> -1/1000 /. px0 -> 1/1000 /. e -> 10^-5

(*-0.007046375030231264`+0.` I*)

Head[a]

(*Complex*)
```

The number is `Real`, but the `Head` turns out to be `Complex` only because it is in the form of `a+Ib`.

If I comment out the condition `If[Head[N[constraint]] === Complex` in the code, it works, but the system hangs after 3 or 4 mouse clicks. How to rectify this issue?

**Edit: Issue resolved**
Thanks to @BobHanlon, the issue is solved.

```
    PoincareSections[{x0_, px0_, y0_, py0_}, e_, tmax_] := 
     Block[{constraint, x, px, y, py}, 
      constraint = 
       N[(I   Sqrt[
             5 + x0]   Sqrt[-12   e + 3   px0^2 - 16   x0^2   (2 + x0)])/
          Sqrt[15]] // Chop;
      If[Head[N[constraint]] === Complex, Nothing, 
       If[# == {}, {}, First[#]] &@
        Last[Reap[
          NDSolve[{hameqns, x[0] == x0, px[0] == px0, y[0] == y0, 
            py[0] == constraint, 
            WhenEvent[y[t], 
             Sow[{x[t], px[t]}, "LocationMethod" -> "EvenLocator"]]}, {x, 
            px, y, py}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> ∞, 
           MaxStepSize -> 0.1]]]]]
    
   style = {PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[.005], Opacity[0.9]}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 420,
   PlotHighlighting -> None};
    
    DynamicModule[{f = {}}, 
     Column[{Dynamic[
        MatrixForm@{MousePosition["Graphics", "Mouse not in graphics!"]}],
        Row[{ClickPane[
          Dynamic@ListPlot[f, 
            style], (AppendTo[f, 
             PoincareSections[{#[[1]], #[[2]], 0, 0}, 10^-5, 3000]]) &], 
         Button[Style["Copy orbit list", 12], 
          CopyToClipboard[Iconize[f, "Orbit list"]], 
          ImageSize -> Automatic, Alignment -> Center, 
          Appearance -> {"Palette", "Pressed"}]}, "  "]}, 
      Alignment -> Center]]
```

### **Choosing the best NDSolve Method**

Rectified code used for a close up:

```
par = {9.07, 11.73, 5.80, 2.18, 4.36, -2.645, 6.023}; {K1, K2, K3, K4,
   K5, ωsq[0], ωsq[1]} = Rationalize[par, 10^-30];
lagrangianold = 
  Sum[c[n]'[t]^2 - c[n][t]^2  ωsq[n], {n, {0, 1}}] + 
   K1  c[0][t]^3 + K2  c[0][t]  c[1][t]^2 + K3  c[0][t]  c[0]'[t]^2 + 
   K4  c[0][t]  c[1]'[t]^2 + K5  c[0]'[t]  c[1][t]  c[1]'[t];
c[0][t_] := 
  OverTilde[c][0][t] + α1*OverTilde[c][0][t]^2 + α2*
    OverTilde[c][1][t]^2; 
c[1][t_] := 
  OverTilde[c][1][t] + α3*OverTilde[c][0][t]*OverTilde[c][1][t];
α1 = -29/20; α2 = -1/2; α3 = -1;
n = Expand[lagrangianold];
vars = {OverTilde[c][0][t], OverTilde[c][1][t], 
   Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][0]][t], 
   Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][1]][t]};
lagrangianew = 
  Normal[Series[n /. Thread[vars -> m*vars], {m, 0, 3}]] /. m -> 1;
    lagrangian = 
  Simplify[
   lagrangianew /. OverTilde[c][0] -> x /. OverTilde[c][1] -> y]; 

Px = D[lagrangian, x'[t]];
Py = D[lagrangian, y'[t]];
hamiltonian = ((Px x'[t] + Py y'[t]) - 
      lagrangian) /. (Solve[{px[t] == Px, py[t] == Py}, {x'[t], 
        y'[t]}] // Last) // FullSimplify;

{a1, b1, c1, d1} = {D[hamiltonian, px[t]], 
  D[hamiltonian, 
   py[t]], -D[hamiltonian, x[t]], -D[hamiltonian, 
    y[t]]}; hameqns = {x'[t] == a1, px'[t] == c1, y'[t] == b1, 
  py'[t] == d1};

constraint = 
 FullSimplify[
  Last[(py0 /. 
     Solve[e == (hamiltonian /. {x[t] -> x0, px[t] -> px0, y[t] -> 0, 
          py[t] -> py0}), py0])]]

PoincareSections[{x0_, px0_, y0_, py0_}, e_, tmax_] := 
 Block[{constraint, x, px, y, py}, 
  constraint = 
   Chop[N[1/50  Sqrt[-5 - (9 x0)/10]
        Sqrt[-2000 e + 500 px0^2 - x0^2 (5290 + 2799 x0)]]];
  If[Head[N[constraint]] === Complex, Nothing, 
   If[# == {}, {}, First[#]] &@
    Last[Reap[
      NDSolve[{hameqns, x[0] == x0, px[0] == px0, y[0] == y0, 
        py[0] == constraint, 
        WhenEvent[y[t], 
         Sow[{x[t], px[t]}, "LocationMethod" -> "EvenLocator"]]}, {x, 
        px, y, py}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> ∞, 
       MaxStepSize -> 0.1, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]]]]]


style = {PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[.005], Opacity[0.9]}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 300, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.0001, 0}, {-0.0001, 0.0001}}, 
   PlotHighlighting -> None};


Off[NDSolve::ndsz]

DynamicModule[{f = {}}, 
 Column[{Dynamic[
    MatrixForm@{MousePosition["Graphics", "Mouse not in graphics!"]}],
    Row[{ClickPane[
      Dynamic@ListPlot[f, 
        style], (AppendTo[f, 
         PoincareSections[{#[[1]], #[[2]], 0, 0}, 10^-5, 2000]]) &], 
     Button[Style["Copy orbit list", 12], 
      CopyToClipboard[Iconize[f, "Orbit list"]], 
      ImageSize -> Automatic, Alignment -> Center, 
      Appearance -> {"Palette", "Pressed"}]}, "  "]}, 
  Alignment -> Center]]
```

I have one minor problem now for a close-up of the above section:
I get an `NDSolve` warning message, which I turn off. Still, the plot I get differs from the original when I use `Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta"` instead of `Automatic` or some other like `"StiffnessSwitching"`.

Here is a result found using two different methods for comparison:

[image: comparison]

Why is it that the results are scaled in the y-axis, and which method should be considered the best in such a case? The methods that I used are also not easily seen in the documentation. Also, any help in making the code more elegant(like avoiding warnings) would be genuinely beneficial!

Comment: In the definition of `PoincareSections` change the definition of `constraint` to read `constraint = N[(I  Sqrt[5 + x0]  Sqrt[-12  e + 3  px0^2 - 16  x0^2  (2 + x0)])/ Sqrt[15]] // Chop;` The `Chop` will remove imaginary artifacts.

Comment: @BobHanlon, thanks a lot. It works now. Can you see the updated question for a minor query?

Comment: @codebpr It could be better to reproduce known results, maybe from your paper as well.

Comment: @AlexTrounev should I ask a new question for that or just update this one to reflect the comparison for reproduced results?

Comment: @codebpr  There is no answer on your topic. Could you add some picture to reproduce with new code?

Comment: @AlexTrounev ok, I am going to add them now.

Comment: You can use [SPRK](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveSPRK.html) methods or `ImplicitRungeKutta` with `ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients` which is also symplectic. [Projection](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveProjection.html) method can be usefull too

Comment: @I.M. thanks for the useful response. I was just wondering why the Wolfram guys have not kept them in the `Options` section of `NDSolve` but hidden inside the `Tutorials`? Also, one query? Why is the result rescaled when I use Hamilton equations of motion instead of Euler- Lagrange?

Comment: The scales seems to match, the integration method for the last left fig is off, I would expect `StiffnessSwitching` to produce wrong result for chaotic systems (got no prove for it thou); I would use `Projection` with Lagrangian eqs (energy conservation) and `SPRK`/`ImplicitRungeKutta` with Hamiltonian eqs

Comment: @I.M. actually, I meant the scale of the [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIjSu.png) compared to the recent ones.

Comment: Also, it gives me lots of errors when I use your suggested `SPRK` method: `Method -> {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 10,
   "PositionVariables" -> {x[t], y[t]}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't know what method is most efficient, since to answer this question we need too much test performed. We can only suggest code without some `NDSolve` messages concerning solution behaver and `WhenEvent`. It seems impossible to exclude all messages. We can't avoid, for example, message which appears when we put mouse on an axis

```
General::munfl: -(1./9.49657*10^307) is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.
```

First, note, that for chaotic system research we should exclude any Automatic option, like automatic step size. Second, note, that all implicit scheme working in this case like averaging, and therefore depresses chaotic mode. Third, note, that `WhenEvent` with some `DetectionMethod` make code unstable. Taken into account all these notes we proposed next options

```
par = {9.07, 11.73, 5.80, 2.18, 4.36, -2.645, 6.023}; {K1, K2, K3, K4,
   K5, \[Omega]sq[0], \[Omega]sq[1]} = Rationalize[par, 10^-30];
lagrangianold = 
  Sum[c[n]'[t]^2 - c[n][t]^2   \[Omega]sq[n], {n, {0, 1}}] + 
   K1   c[0][t]^3 + K2   c[0][t]   c[1][t]^2 + 
   K3   c[0][t]   c[0]'[t]^2 + K4   c[0][t]   c[1]'[t]^2 + 
   K5   c[0]'[t]   c[1][t]   c[1]'[t];
c[0][t_] := 
  OverTilde[c][0][t] + \[Alpha]1*OverTilde[c][0][t]^2 + \[Alpha]2*
    OverTilde[c][1][t]^2;
c[1][t_] := 
  OverTilde[c][1][t] + \[Alpha]3*OverTilde[c][0][t]*OverTilde[c][1][t];
\[Alpha]1 = -29/20; \[Alpha]2 = -1/2; \[Alpha]3 = -1;
n = Expand[lagrangianold];
vars = {OverTilde[c][0][t], OverTilde[c][1][t], 
   Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][0]][t], 
   Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][1]][t]};
lagrangianew = 
  Normal[Series[n /. Thread[vars -> m*vars], {m, 0, 3}]] /. m -> 1;
lagrangian = 
  Simplify[
   lagrangianew /. OverTilde[c][0] -> x /. OverTilde[c][1] -> y];

Px = D[lagrangian, x'[t]];
Py = D[lagrangian, y'[t]];
hamiltonian = ((Px  x'[t] + Py  y'[t]) - 
      lagrangian) /. (Solve[{px[t] == Px, py[t] == Py}, {x'[t], 
        y'[t]}] // Last) // FullSimplify;

{a1, b1, c1, d1} = {D[hamiltonian, px[t]], 
  D[hamiltonian, 
   py[t]], -D[hamiltonian, x[t]], -D[hamiltonian, 
    y[t]]}; hameqns = {x'[t] == a1, px'[t] == c1, y'[t] == b1, 
  py'[t] == d1};

constraint = 
  FullSimplify[
   Last[(py0 /. 
      Solve[e == (hamiltonian /. {x[t] -> x0, px[t] -> px0, y[t] -> 0,
            py[t] -> py0}), py0])]];

PoincareSections[{x0_, px0_, y0_, py0_}, e_, tmax_] := 
 Block[{constraint, x, px, y, py}, 
  constraint = 
   Chop[N[1/
       50   Sqrt[-5 - (9  x0)/10]  Sqrt[-2000  e + 500  px0^2 - 
        x0^2  (5290 + 2799  x0)]]];
  If[Head[N[constraint]] === Complex, Nothing, 
   If[# == {}, {}, First[#]] &@
    Last[Reap[
      NDSolve[{hameqns, x[0] == x0, px[0] == px0, y[0] == y0, 
        py[0] == constraint, 
        WhenEvent[y[t], Sow[{x[t], px[t]}], 
         "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"]}, {x, px, y, py}, {t, 
        0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], StartingStepSize -> 0.1, 
       Method -> {"FixedStep", 
         Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 8}}]]]]]


style = {PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[.005], Opacity[0.5]}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 500, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.0001, 0}, {-0.0001, 0.0001}}, 
   PlotHighlighting -> None, Frame -> True, Background -> Black};


(*Off[NDSolve::ndsz]*)

DynamicModule[{f = {}}, 
 Column[{Dynamic[
    MatrixForm@{MousePosition["Graphics", "Mouse not in graphics!"]}],
    Row[{ClickPane[
      Dynamic@ListPlot[f, 
        style], (AppendTo[f, 
         PoincareSections[{#[[1]], #[[2]], 0, 0}, 10^-5, 2000]]) &], 
     Button[Style["Copy orbit list", 12], 
      CopyToClipboard[Iconize[f, "Orbit list"]], 
      ImageSize -> Automatic, Alignment -> Center, 
      Appearance -> {"Palette", "Pressed"}]}, "  "]}, 
  Alignment -> Center]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Using this code we can performed research with step size decreasing.

Comment: Many thanks for this! Just a small query, when I tried testing with [SPRK](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveSPRK.html) method, I don't get any points. Here's what I used: `Method -> {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 8,    "PositionVariables" -> {x[t], y[t]}}`

Comment: @codebpr Hamiltonian `hamiltonian` is not separable. Therefore SPRK has been replaced in this case by Automatic method. In turn Automatic method is optimized for variable step size that leads to "StiffnessSwitching"  and automatic `Stop`.